# How to dispatching an email or a message box when something happend on a folder to another local machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows Server which some local users put files that I need to manage quickly, however, I can't see my server every hour. There is a way to Windows Server itselfs warns me that I need to take care of new files of the shared folder? Someone knows if there are some free aplication that does it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some options on another post:

- [Directory-Monitor](http://brutaldev.com/page/Directory-Monitor.aspx)
- [Filehamster](http://www.filehamster.com/)
- [Foldertrack](http://www.foldertrack.com/)